# Динамическое заполнение FlatList в React Native

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

Есть FlatList и его элементы представлены в массиве. Нужно, чтобы по заполнению формы эти данные добавлялись в массив и отображались в списке. Но почему-то при добавлении объекта происходит не то, что нужно: добавляется только один элемент (размер массива не может увеличиться больше чем на 3 элемента), и список не обновляется. Как это можно исправить? В приведённом ниже примере кода данные из формы выдаются из объекта во внешнем классе Forms.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Forms } from '../components/Forms';

export default function HomeScreen() {

  var listElements = [
    { id : "0", text : "Object 1"},
    { id : "1", text : "Object 2"},
  ]

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data = {listElements}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
            <Text>{item.text}<Text/>
          }
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
        <Button
          title="Add element"
          onPress={() => {
            var forms = new Forms();
            listElements.push({id: forms.data.id, text: forms.data.text});
            // DEBUG
            for(let i = 0; i < reminders.length; i++) {
              console.log(listElements[i].text);
            }
            console.log(listElements.length);        
          }}
        <
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно менять состояние, сделать это можно:
1) Либо используя хуки (https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) 
2) либо преобразуйте функцию HomeScreen в класс, и используйте state. 
Из ретурна изменять(мутировать) данные функции вы не можете.

Дополнительно:

```
<Button
      title="Add element"
      onPress={() => {
        var forms = new Forms();
        listElements.push({id: forms.data.id, text: forms.data.text});
        // DEBUG
        for(let i = 0; i < reminders.length; i++) {
          console.log(listElements[i].text);
        }
        console.log(listElements.length);        
      }}
    <
```

вычисления не применяйте в этом ретурне, в данном случае ретурн выступает как рендер. Лучше сделайте onPress={() => calculation()} , и до ретурна эти вычисления.